# window.open() from angular material $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Im using the angular material $mdDialog service to open a dialog.
When the user clicks on the *OK* button i want to open a new tab and navigate to a different url.

The problem is, is that the browser pop-up blocker (tested on chrome/safari) blocks the new tab from opening since the action is indirect from the user's click (as i understand).

Im using the $mdDialog example from the site:

```
$scope.showConfirm = function(ev) {
  var confirm = $mdDialog.confirm()
      .title('Would you like to delete your debt?')
      .textContent('All of the banks have agreed to forgive you your debts.')
      .ariaLabel('Lucky day')
      .targetEvent(ev)
      .ok('Please do it!')
      .cancel('Sounds like a scam');

  $mdDialog.show(confirm).then(function() {
    $scope.status = 'You decided to get rid of your debt.';
    $window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); // <--- this is blocked
  }, function() {
    $scope.status = 'You decided to keep your debt.';
  });
};
```

Comment: So why not opening the new window from the `button`'s `ng-click` instead of  the callback?

Comment: The OK button is autogenerated by the $mdDialog service

Comment: It doesn't have to be, you can use your own `template`. i don't see any other way (unless you want to change `material`'s src..).

Comment: Different URL or different state in the app ?

Comment: @nextt - different url.